# Loading html string in webview when offline

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
self.webView.loadHTMLString(bodyText, baseURL: nil)
```

I saved the bodyText in FileManager to be loaded when the user is offline.

However, the didFinish method is not being called when loadHtmlString is called when the user is offline.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Show more relevant code. Did you set the `navigationDelegate`?